# add top or bottom border to broken tables printed using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: css, html, wkhtmltopdf

I use wkhtmltopdf to generate PDF files from html files that were generated automatically. I have several tables in these html files, and when printed into PDF using wkhtmltopdf, some tables could be broken into several pages. I want to add bottom border and top border to these broken tables, but could not find a working method.

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Ying